# How to solve TS7022 error in Vue Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, vue-composition-api

Im getting this error when i try to import a component in my file:

```
TS7022: 'default' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
Version: typescript 4.2.2, eslint 7.32.0
```

Here is my script tag:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import OrdersTable from 'src/components/OrdersTable.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: { OrdersTable }
})
</script>
```

Comment: It's unknown why you use `src` for absolute path and what's your setup.

Answer (score 3):

It could mean that you have a looped imports your components. Check dependencies of OrdersTable (all nested imports) that it does not have a import of this component

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31853752)